# How can I make my program installable via the linux repositories (eg, using apt-get)?

Tags: linux, installation, apt-get

I have created a program and I would like it to be installable via commands such as 'apt-get' on linux, but I have no idea where to even begin to achieve this. Could someone help and explain what I need to do to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this would get better, and more, responses in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). In any case, you should indicate which distribution we are talking about there, apt-get runs on any Debian-derivative and each distribution has, of course, different policy of how/when/what to include.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to install your own package via apt-get you need to:

1. Package your application as a deb.
2. Add your package to an apt-repository.
3. Configure your distribution to use said apt-repository.

Creating a package and a repository takes a bit of work. A step by step will be quite long and depend a lot on the app your packaging. There are multiple ways of creating packages, and multiple ways of creating repositories. In general though, here are some pointers for utilities that can help you:

**Creating packages:**

Have a look at [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). It's a nice and easy utility that can create packages for multiple formats, including deb. Have a look at [this guide](http://www.ducea.com/2011/08/31/build-your-own-packages-easily-with-fpm/) for an idea of how to use it.

**Creating a repository:**

I've mostly used reprepro for this in the past. Check out [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-an-apt-repository-with-reprepro-and-nginx-on-debian-wheezy).
The above guide also includes how to use the repo after it has been published.